# Prevent multiple instances of a given app in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

In .NET, how can I prevent multiple instances of an app from running at the same time and what caveats should I consider if there are multiple ways to do it?

Comment: Hanselman has [a post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx) on using the WinFormsApplicationBase class from the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly to do this.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Use Mutex. One of the examples above using GetProcessByName has many caveats. Here is a good article on the subject:

https://web.archive.org/web/20230610150623/https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2004/08/20/the-misunderstood-mutex.aspx

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() 
{
   using(Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "Global\\" + appGuid))
   {
      if(!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Instance already running");
         return;
      }
   
      Application.Run(new Form1());
   }
}

private static string appGuid = "c0a76b5a-12ab-45c5-b9d9-d693faa6e7b9";
```

Comment: Using a mutex also works for non .net code as well (although the syntax would vary)

Comment: Here's a slightly more filled-out version, with some good comments:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c/229567

Comment: @ClarkKent: Just a random string so that the Mutex name wont collide the name from another application.

Comment: Can this restrict to a certain number of instances too?

Comment: this doesn't work for me, I have found the GUID from the Project Settings of application1, which I want to check. While running application1 I launch application2, which should check if application1 is running. It doesn't give me an error messagebox.

Comment: What do you do if you are using C#/WPF where there is no explicit main method? I don't want to explicitly declare a main since it is being auto-generated with some additional content.

Comment: In order to have a better control while versioning or changing your app guid, you can use: `string appGuid = ((GuidAttribute)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true)[0]).Value;` which will get the executing assembly's guid

Comment: I think an important caveat to Mutex is this: The Mutex class enforces thread identity, so a mutex can be released only by the thread that acquired it. By contrast, the Semaphore class does not enforce thread identity. A mutex can also be passed across application domain boundaries.

Comment: @yellavon create a .cs file, put in `namespace your_app {public partial class App { private void ApplicationStart(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) { ... } } }`, then set `<Application ... Startup="ApplicationStart">` in `App.config`

Comment: Doesn't this answer depend on `Application.Run()` not returning until the application exits? I don't know how it works, but I would've thought a multithreaded application couldn't depend on something like that. `Application.Run()` is for Windows Forms, isn't it? In WPF, we're not even supposed to use the "Main" method at all, right?

Comment: How could this be the answer!? This doesn't work at all.

Comment: It took me a while to realize that the above code only works, if the mutex exists as long as the instance is running. I removed the using block and changed the mutex variable to be static (or shared in vb.net). After that everything worked as expected.

Comment: Why the GUID? Just my app name is fairly unique in the users' computer. Any special case for the GUID?

Answer (score 28):

Here is the code you need to ensure that only one instance is running. This is the method of using a named mutex.

```
public class Program
{
    static System.Threading.Mutex singleton = new Mutex(true, "My App Name");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (!singleton.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        {
            //there is already another instance running!
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a WPF application use Application.Current.Shutdown();  This method works like a charm. Thanks Terrapin.

Comment: Here the main thing is you make mutex static. As well as in the other case GC will collect it.

Comment: I enjoyed the simplicity and clarity of the named Mutex. This code is concise and effective.

Answer (score 26):

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length > 1)
{
  AppLog.Write("Application XXXX already running. Only one instance of this application is allowed", AppLog.LogMessageType.Warn);
  return;
}
```

Comment: I think that should see this:http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2004/08/20/the-misunderstood-mutex.aspx

Comment: @SubmarineX How you sure this article is correct? it is still controversy between mutex and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4975/Easily-Create-A-Single-Instance-Application

Comment: Amazing Just perfect 
thanks for your time and efforts

Comment: -1 While this is the quick solution, it is also very easy to circumvent a.exe could be renamed to b.exe and both will run. + other cases where this simply wont work as intended. Use with caution!

Comment: This does not work with mono-develop. Under windows environments it works great though.

Answer (score 11):

1 - Create a reference in program.cs ->

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

2 - Put into `void Main()` as the first line of code ->

```
 if (Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length >1)
                return;
```

That's it.

Comment: What's the difference of this to `Mutex`? Is there a catch?

Comment: It's using the name of the process. If the name is repeated then it would generate a false flag.   In any other case, it's cleaner than mutex

Answer (score 7):

After trying multiple solutions i the question. I ended up using the example for **WPF** here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f9f215/how-to-restrict-the-application-to-just-one-instance/

```
public partial class App : Application  
{  
    private static Mutex _mutex = null;  

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)  
    {  
        const string appName = "MyAppName";  
        bool createdNew;  

        _mutex = new Mutex(true, appName, out createdNew);  

        if (!createdNew)  
        {  
            //app is already running! Exiting the application  
            Application.Current.Shutdown();  
        }  

    }          
}
```

In App.xaml:

```
x:Class="*YourNameSpace*.App"
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
Startup="App_Startup"
```

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like there are 3 fundamental techniques that have been suggested so far.

1. Derive from the Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase class and set the IsSingleInstance property to true. (I believe a caveat here is that this won't work with WPF applications, will it?)
2. Use a named mutex and check if it's already been created.
3. Get a list of running processes and compare the names of the processes. (This has the caveat of requiring your process name to be unique relative to any other processes running on a given user's machine.)

Any caveats I've missed?

Comment: I don't think 3 is very efficient. I'd vote for the Mutex, used it without problems many times. I've never used item 1 not sure how that flies when you're in c#.

Comment: Option 1 still works with WPF it's just slightly more involved.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771662.aspx

Answer (score 5):

i tried all the solutions here and nothing worked in my C# .net 4.0 project. Hoping to help someone here the solution that worked for me:

As main class variables:

```
private static string appGuid = "WRITE AN UNIQUE GUID HERE";
private static Mutex mutex;
```

When you need to check if app is already running:

```
bool mutexCreated;
mutex = new Mutex(true, "Global\\" + appGuid, out mutexCreated);
if (mutexCreated)
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();

if (!mutexCreated)
{
    //App is already running, close this!
    Environment.Exit(0); //i used this because its a console app
}
```

I needed to close other istances only with some conditions, this worked well for my purpose

Comment: You don't need to actually acquire the mutex and release it. All you need to know is if another app has already created the object (i.e., its kernel reference count>=1).

Answer (score 4):

Using Visual Studio 2005 or 2008, when you create a project for an executable, on the properties windows inside the "Application" panel, there is a check box named “Make single instance application” that you can activate to convert the application on a single instance application.

Here is a capture of the window I'm talking of:

[image]

This is a Visual Studio 2008 windows application project.

Comment: I looked for this checkbox you mention, for my C#/WPF app, and there isn't any.

Comment: I don't see it in my VS 2008 C#/WinForms app's properties either.

Comment: Not in VS2005 as well. He must be mentioning old VB studio.

Comment: Yes the option exists, I modified the post to add a capture of the window in which you can find this option.

Comment: The option exists only for VB.NET application, not for C#. Apparently the option itself uses WinFormsApplicationBase class from the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.

Answer (score 3):

This is the code for VB.Net

```
Private Shared Sub Main()
    Using mutex As New Mutex(False, appGuid)
        If Not mutex.WaitOne(0, False) Then
              MessageBox.Show("Instance already running", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return
        End If

        Application.Run(New Form1())
    End Using
End Sub
```

This is the code for C#

```
private static void Main()
{
    using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, appGuid)) {
        if (!mutex.WaitOne(0, false)) {
            MessageBox.Show("Instance already running", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }

        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use VB.NET!
No: really ;)

using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;

The WindowsFormsApplicationBase from VB.Net provides you with a "SingleInstace" Property, which determines other Instances and let only one Instance run.

Answer (score 2):

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()                  // args are OK here, of course
{
    bool ok;
    m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "YourNameHere", out ok);

    if (! ok)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Another instance is already running.");
        return;
    }

    Application.Run(new Form1());   // or whatever was there

    GC.KeepAlive(m);                // important!
}
```

From: [Ensuring a single instance of .NET Application](http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/SingleInstance.html)

and: [Single Instance Application Mutex](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SingleInstanceAppMutex.aspx)

Same answer as @Smink and @Imjustpondering with a twist:

[Jon Skeet's FAQ on C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/faq/) to find out why [GC.KeepAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx) matters

Comment: -1, because you fail to use a using block with the mutex, which would make the KeepAlive superfluous. And yes, I do think John Skeet got this one wrong. He doesn't elaborate why it would be wrong to Dispose the mutex in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Simply using a `StreamWriter`, how about this?

```
System.IO.File.StreamWriter OpenFlag = null;   //globally
```

and

```
try
{
    OpenFlag = new StreamWriter(Path.GetTempPath() + "OpenedIfRunning");
}
catch (System.IO.IOException) //file in use
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use System.Diagnostics.Process.

Check out: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/20044

Answer (score 1):

*(Note: this is a fun-solution! It works but uses bad GDI+ design to achieve this.)*

Put an image in with your app and load it on startup. Hold it until the app exits. The user wont be able to start a 2nd instance. *(Of course the mutex solution is much cleaner)*

```
private static Bitmap randomName = new Bitmap("my_image.jpg");
```

Comment: This is actually brilliant in its simplicity, and it works with pretty much any kind of file and not just images. I feel like the Mutex solution is far from "clean." It's extremely complicated and there are apparently many ways for it to fail on account of not doing it "right." It also requires a `Main()` method which goes against how WPF is supposed to work.

Comment: This is kind of like bug using. It works but it's not made for that purpose. I wouldn't use it as a professional.

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate we don't have a solution this effective and simple without relying on exceptions.

Comment: Though it's not exactly a bug. It's still .NET behaving as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it's done with a named Mutex (use new Mutex( "your app name", true ) and check the return value), but there's also some support classes in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll that [can do it for you](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in pure C#.  the try/catch is when possibly a process in the list exits during your loop.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
....
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
...
        int procCount = 0;
        foreach (Process pp in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            try
            {
                if (String.Compare(pp.MainModule.FileName, Application.ExecutablePath, true) == 0)
                {
                    procCount++;                        
                    if(procCount > 1) {
                       Application.Exit();
                       return;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
        Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to consider security when restricting an application to a single instance:

Full article:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060620-13/?p=30813

> We are using a named mutex with a fixed name in order to detect
>   whether another copy of the program is running. But that also means an
>   attacker can create the mutex first, thereby preventing our program
>   from running at all! How can I prevent this type of denial of service
>   attack?

...

> If the attacker is running in the same security context as your
>   program is (or would be) running in, then there is nothing you can do.
>   Whatever "secret handshake" you come up with to determine whether
>   another copy of your program is running, the attacker can mimic it.
>   Since it is running in the correct security context, it can do
>   anything that the "real" program can do.

...

> Clearly you can't protect yourself from an attacker running at the
>   same security privilege, but you can still protect yourself against
>   unprivileged attackers running at other security privileges.

Try setting a DACL on your mutex, here's the .NET way:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.mutexsecurity(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

None of this answers worked for me because I needed this to work under Linux using monodevelop. This works great for me:

Call this method passing it a unique ID

```
    public static void PreventMultipleInstance(string applicationId)
    {
        // Under Windows this is:
        //      C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Temp\ 
        // Linux this is:
        //      /tmp/
        var temporaryDirectory = Path.GetTempPath();

        // Application ID (Make sure this guid is different accross your different applications!
        var applicationGuid = applicationId + ".process-lock";

        // file that will serve as our lock
        var fileFulePath = Path.Combine(temporaryDirectory, applicationGuid);

        try
        {
            // Prevents other processes from reading from or writing to this file
            var _InstanceLock = new FileStream(fileFulePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
            _InstanceLock.Lock(0, 0);
            MonoApp.Logger.LogToDisk(LogType.Notification, "04ZH-EQP0", "Aquired Lock", fileFulePath);

            // todo investigate why we need a reference to file stream. Without this GC releases the lock!
            System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer()
            {
                Interval = 500000,
                Enabled = true,
            };
            t.Elapsed += (a, b) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    _InstanceLock.Lock(0, 0);
                }
                catch
                {
                    MonoApp.Logger.Log(LogType.Error, "AOI7-QMCT", "Unable to lock file");
                }
            };
            t.Start();

        }
        catch
        {
            // Terminate application because another instance with this ID is running
            Environment.Exit(102534); 
        }
    }
```