# Exit Application from ApplicationContext

Tags: c#, .net

I have a custom ApplicationContext and I'm trying to terminate it if specific conditions are met.  I am using a Mutex to ensure a single instance.

I've tried `base.OnMainFormClosed(null, null);`. `Application.Exit()` and `ExitThread`.  Everything stops processing, but the process itself is still running.

Complete Main() method:

```
static void Main()
    {
        bool firstInstance;
        using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true,
                                   @"Global\MyApplication",
                                   out firstInstance))
        {
            if (!firstInstance)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Another instance is already running.");
                return;
            }

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Application.Run(new CustomContext());
        }
    }
```

What's the correct technique?

Comment: What's in your `Main` method?

Comment: `Application.Run(new CustomContext());`

Comment: Are You using any constructors or some thing in your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
   Application.Run(new CustomContext());
```

That's okay, but you don't store a reference to the CustomContext object you created.  There's thus no way to call its ExitThread method.  Tweak it like this:

```
class Program {
    private static CustomContext appContext;

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main() {
       // Init code
       //...
       appContext = new CustomContext();
       Application.Run(appContext);
    }
    public static void Quit() {
        appContext.ExitThread();
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call Program.Quit() to stop the message loop.

Check my answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697058/single-instance-windows-forms-application-and-how-to-get-reference-on-it) for a better way to implement a single-instance app.  The WindowsFormsApplicationBase class also offers the ShutdownStyle property, probably useful to you instead of ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Application.Exit` stops your program's message loop.
This causes the main `Application.Run` call (typically in `Main()`) to terminate.

After calling `Applcication.Exit()`, any code in `Main()` after the `Application.Run()` call will execute.

`Application.Run` is typically the last line in `Main()`, so calling `Applcication.Exit()` will usually cause the process to stop.

You probably have more code after `Application.Run()`, or a deadlock somewhere in disposal.

---

Pause the process in a debugger and check what it's doing.

Comment: The debugger pauses on the `Application.Run` line.  The call stack is showing `[External Code]` above and below.

I am also using a mutex to ensure a single instance, which I probably should have pointed out at the start.  I'll update the question with the complete method.

Answer (score -2):

You can just call in thread that you want to exit

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
```