# File locks for linux

Tags: c, linux, file, locking

I tried using temp files:

```
char *temp = tempnam(NULL, "myapp_");
printf("Tempname: %s", temp)     // Prints /tmp/myapp_random
while (1) { }
```

But when I check `/tmp` (while the app is still running), the myapp_random is not there!

As for using File Locks, I can't get a good grasp on it, I tried looking at `<fcntl.h>` but it seems to focus on locks in specified portions of a file. I just want to use the file entirely as a lock (which is why I prefer trying the temp file approach).

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800730/c-c-how-to-tell-if-a-program-is-already-running

Comment: @Richard, that question was specifically for Windows. This one is almost certainly a UNIXy-type one since (1) `tempnam` was deprecated in VC2005, (2) the code references `/tmp/myapp_random` which is not really a Windows thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`tempnam` doesn't *create* the file, it just gives you a filename that didn't exist at the time you called it.

You still have to *create* the file yourself and therefore still have the race condition that another process may sneak in and create it before you.

You don't actually *want* to use `tempnam` since that will give each process its own file name and they will be able to run concurrently. What you need is a *fixed* file name (like `/tmp/myapp.lck` for example) which each process opens and then attempts to `flock`.

You're better off with `flock` for a lock file, `fcntl` will give you a finer grain of locking (parts of files) but that's not really a requirement here.

The code would run something like this:

```
if ((mylockfd = open ("/tmp/myapp.lck", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666)) < 0) {
    // error, couldn't open it.
    return;
}
if (flock (mylockfd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) < 0) {
    // error, couldn't exclusive-lock it.
    return;
}
:
// Weave your magic here.
:
flock (mylockfd, LOCK_UN);
```

That probably needs some work but should be a good start. A more generalised solution would be something like:

```
int acquireLock (char *fileSpec) {
    int lockFd;

    if ((lockFd = open (fileSpec, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666))  < 0)
        return -1;

    if (flock (mylockfd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) < 0) {
        close (lockFd);
        return -1;
    }

    return lockFd;
}

void releaseLock (int lockFd) {
    flock (lockFd, LOCK_UN);
    close (lockFd);
}

// Calling code here.

int fd;
if ((fd = acquireLock ("/tmp/myapp.lck")) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Cannot get lock file.\n");
    return 1;
}

// Weave your magic here.

releaseLock (fd);
```

Comment: A million thanks!! YAY :D the 0_CREAT | 0_RDWR, 0666 worked... I think before you only had 0_CREAT but this is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is it safe to have the `close` after `flock(lockFd, LOCK_UN)`? Could this not lead to undefined behavior ?