# Launch single console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

> Possible duplicate: [Run single instance of an application using Mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819773/run-single-instance-of-an-application-using-mutex)

I am using VS 2008 in C# on a console application. Not sure if there is any class available (process?) to limit only single console application running at a time.

Comment: Did you mean to run just one instance of the program?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a dupe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such class, but you can use [System.Threading.Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) to build one.

Mutex is a synchronization primitive that can also be used for interprocess synchronization.

**See example:** [How ensure that only one instance of an application will run?](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ:_How_ensure_that_only_one_instance_of_an_application_will_run)

Answer (score 1):

I quickly slapped this together, but it does show the second console briefly and then hides it. Not sure if there's a way to block the second console from even showing up...

```
class Program
{
    private static Mutex mutex;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        mutex = new Mutex(true, "MyMutex");
        if (!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
        {
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Application started");
        Console.ReadKey(true);

    }
}
```

You'll need to add a reference to System.Threading.