# Select And Open Multiple Files in the C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, instance, windows

When I Select Multiple Files in My Computer And Open , each File Open with one Instance in My Application. In Configure Windows Application to Run One Instance,But One File Open with My Application.How Can I Open Selected Files And Add Address Files in a List Box in My Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can control single instance of your application..For example see this thread: [Run single instance of an application using Mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819773/run-single-instance-of-an-application-using-mutex). If you want your program to open multiple files-you'll have to pass some parameters to your program when checking its running instances or something like this.