# launching another C# application

Tags: c#, launching-application

I have two C# applications (Windows Forms). Both developed by myself. I want one application to launch the other and open a form related to a parameter passed from first application. If second application is already open, then I need only to open the form in second application and get it to front.

Comment: Search for Inter process communication using C#

Comment: What types of C# applications are you referring to? Console Applications? Forms Applications? Web Applications? There are quite a few C# applications and the answer may differ in function of their type.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to archieve this is
that your 2 c# applications
support command line arguments
and are able to communicate together

[Main() and Command-Line Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx)

[Interprocess Communications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx#base.using_data_copy_for_ipc)

look also at
[Data Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648710%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Command line Arguments I agree, but it is only for first launch. What we can do if it is already running ?

Comment: Data Copy can we use this for C# applications ?

Comment: of course, but you have to use p/invoke. In the interprocess communications link are some different ways for archieving this. Also good approaches are Remoting and Pipes!

Answer (score 0):

First step:
Launch an application if not launched
1)Determine, if application is running: [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722198/checking-if-windows-application-is-running)
2)If is not runnign, run application: [MSDN Example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/06/01/146375.aspx)

Second step:
Then try named pipes for interprocess communication: [Example here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp)