# Mutex results are varying in systems

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mutex

I have a console application in C# and I want to restrict my application to run only one instance at a time.It's work fine in one system.When i try to run the exe in another system it's not working.The problem is In one pc i can open only one exe. When i try to run on another pc i can open more than one exe.How can i resolve this issue? Below are the code i have written.

```
string mutexId = Application.ProductName;
using (var mutex = new Mutex(false, mutexId))
{
    if (!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Instance Already Running!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        return;
    }

        //Remaining Code here
}
```

Comment: What other system is it not working in can you be more specific JEMI

Comment: What do you mean by another system? Another PC?

Comment: "It's not working" is *never* enough detail. You should *always* explain what you expect to see and what you're *actually* seeing.

Comment: Yes.It's not working in another PC

Comment: What's not working in the other PC?

Comment: I can open two exe's in another PC.

Comment: Have you thought about refactoring the way that the Mutex and the check to see if an existing application is running..? please see this stackoverflow post it's very straight forward http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819773/run-single-instance-of-an-application-using-mutex

Comment: In one pc i can open only one exe. When i try to run on another pc i can open more than one exe

Comment: Is i need to update the question?

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me: One one PC it detects the previous instance, and on a different PC it doesn't.

Comment: I think you need to add `mutex.ReleaseMutex()`; before the closing brace of your using statement. The JIT may be deciding to Dispose/GC the Mutex

Answer (score 1):

I would use this approach instead anyway:

```
// Use a named EventWaitHandle to determine if the application is already running.

bool eventWasCreatedByThisInstance;

using (new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, Application.ProductName, out eventWasCreatedByThisInstance))
{
    if (eventWasCreatedByThisInstance)
    {
        runTheProgram();
        return;
    }
    else // This instance didn't create the event, therefore another instance must be running.
    {
        return; // Display warning message here if you need it.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My good old solution:

```
    private static bool IsAlreadyRunning()
    {
        string strLoc = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        FileSystemInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(strLoc);
        string sExeName = fileInfo.Name;
        bool bCreatedNew;

        Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "Global\\"+sExeName, out bCreatedNew);
        if (bCreatedNew)
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();

        return !bCreatedNew;
    }
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722198/checking-if-windows-application-is-running)