# How to know when any application is opened or closed in Windows using C#?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

How to know when any application is opened or closed in Windows 8 or 10 using C#?

Is there any specific event we can subscribe?

Comment: I'm not saying there isn't one, but I've not heard of an event for this. You could instead regularly get a list of all running processes and compare the new list to the values from last time. The difference between the two would let you know what has opened and closed.

Comment: @i486 I think you know what the OP means when they state `using C#` come on now..

Comment: The linked answer doesn't show exactly how to monitor applications closing, but you just use the `__InstanceDeletionEvent` in exactly the same way as the linked answer uses `__InstanceCreationEvent`.

Comment: Not sure if this is an *exact* duplicate, but this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/net-process-monitor

Comment: @LaPuyaLoca you can use the `Process` class you could even look into `Mutex` but that's a bit more advanced also check this previous post out this will do the trick for you [Checking if Windows application is running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722198/checking-if-a-windows-application-is-running)

Comment: @i486 C# is the Microsoft programming language used in VisualStudio