# How do I show an error message if a program is not running?

Tags: vb.net, process, msgbox

I would like to write a piece of code that will check if a program is running and if it isn't then a `MsgBox` will appear. I have done this before with a specific file using the code below:

```
If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("\\twa-file2\staffhomes\" + TextBox1.Text)) Then
    MsgBox("Home Area Not Found", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")
End If
```

Would someone be able to tell me how to do this for a program?

Comment: I think your mixing what you want to do. Either you want to check if a file exists (what your doing in your code) or you want to check if a process is running.

Comment: If you're checking if a program is running (as opposed to simply looking to see if a directory exists, as your posted code indicates), then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722198/checking-if-my-windows-application-is-running may be a helpful starting point. Then you can simply modify your condition accordingly.

Comment: Side note; use `MessageBox` instead of `MsgBox`. You should look at Googling how to check if a process is running.

Comment: medric - I would to know how to do it for a process. The directory code was just an example of what ive done with a directory. I would like to do the same but with a process.

Comment: Chris - that in c# and unfortunately I'm not clever enough to know what it means I have tried a code converter but to know avail.

Comment: @KyleSnelling True, it's for C#, but the key part is [`Process.GetProcesses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx), which can be used in any .NET language (including VB.NET). This method is already suggested in an answer below, which includes a link to MSDN where code samples are provided in C#, C++ and VB.NET.

Comment: I now have the following code: localByName As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("pc-client.exe") how would I then make it so a message box appears if it does not find the process?

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at the [Process.GetProcesses Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: i now have the following code: localByName As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("pc-client.exe") how would I then make it so a message box appears if it does not find the process?

Comment: You would need to check the length of the array returned. If the length is 0 then the process is not running.

Comment: what's an array and how do I go about doing that? I really an very basic with VB and just trying to find my feet.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the tutorials/documenation: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/topics however if you are unfamiliar with the concept of an array you may want to consider some programming basics