# Mono alternative for named Mutex

Tags: c#, linux, mono, synchronization

On Windows/.NET, a named Mutex can be used to synchronise multiple processes. Unfortunately, Mono doesn't quite support this on Linux. Their [release notes](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.8#Shared_handles_are_disabled_by_default) say that Linux doesn't support this Windows feature and it would be unreliable to emulate it. It seems best to avoid the proposed hack to enable it anyway.

So what are suggested alternatives? I need to make my program safe to run concurrently, only a short section of it needs to be synchronised with other instances.

The application eventually needs to be deployed on Ubuntu Linux with Mono 2.10, but for testing, it would be highly appreciated if it also works on Windows 7 with .NET 4.

Comment: You could write a C (or C++) wrapper and glue code for Mono around some Linux synchronization primitives (see Posix semaphores and [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) etc...)

Comment: Actually I don't know how to glue Mono, I can just use it, with C#. Also this wouldn't be cross-platform at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Try to look at http://aakinshin.net/en/blog/dotnet/namedmutex-on-mono/

**OLD:**
Mono does not support any Windows-native IPC.
So you do not have for example Named Pipes, or Mutexes.

But to **sync threads** in the same process you can use [Monitor class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explicitly (it also used for lock).

To simply **notify another process** you can try to use [Unix Domain Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket).
Check [UnixEndPoint](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T:Mono.Posix.UnixEndPoint#) class for that. One of benefits you can specify name for it (like for named semaphore for example).

Also you can try to **emulate Mutex** using own file. Try to get exclusive access to specific own file. While you have that access - you are in critical section.

Comment: things are very different now - http://aakinshin.net/en/blog/dotnet/namedmutex-on-mono/

Comment: yes it can be... especially when MS acquired Xamaring and want to promote .Net Core. I will update answer with you link...