# Windows App Certification Kit fails: Multi user session test

Tags: c#, windows, desktop-application, app-certification-kit, wack

I'm trying to pull a WinForms application through the Windows App Certification Kit and gets a fail on this test:

```
  <TEST INDEX="17" NAME="Multi user session test" DESCRIPTION="Multi User checks Application invocation in multiple sessions." EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:24s.22ms">
  <RESULT><![CDATA[FAIL]]></RESULT>
  <MESSAGES />
```

I guess that this is because I only allow one instance of the application to run, like this:

```
using ( var p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess() )
if ( System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName( p.ProcessName ).Length > 1 )
{
    MessageBox.Show(
            "An instance of xxx is already running!",
            Title,
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation );
    return;
 }
```

It is a tray-application activated by a hot-key combination, registered with this function:

```
[DllImport( "user32", EntryPoint = "RegisterHotKey", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true )]
public static extern int RegisterHotkey( IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk );
```

So I guess I have two questions:

1) How can I correctly prevent multiple sessions being run within the same user session but allow several instances across multiple user sessions?

2) Will I be able to register the same hot-key in different user sessions? Or must I somehow unregister and re-register the hot-key when user sessions are switched?

TIA

Comment: Using a mutex I think is a better way to prevent multiple instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same effect using a [`Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  See MSDN for details, but the short version is that any mutex created with a name starting with `"Local\"`  will be per-session.  Enter a mutex named `"Local\MyAppName"` and only one instance of your app can run per-session.

Hotkeys are registered per-session and it will not be a problem to register the same hotkey in multiple sessions.

Example Use (from [Run single instance of an application using Mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819773/run-single-instance-of-an-application-using-mutex)):

```
bool ownsMutex = false;
// NOTE: Local is the default namespace, so the name could be shortened to myApp
Mutex myMutex = new Mutex(false, @"Local\myApp");

try 
{
    ownsMutex = myMutex.WaitOne(0)
}
catch (AbandonedMutexException)
{
    ownsMutex = true;
}

if (!ownsMutex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("myApp is already running!", "Multiple Instances");
    return;
}
else 
{
    try 
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    finally 
    {
        myMutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```