# How to check my exe is running in background process. If not need to initiate

Tags: c#, windows-services

I created a windows service in which the code will execute every 1 seconds

My code

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("my_process").Length > 0)
 {
   writelog("Started uploading files");
   upload_file();
   writelog("Finished uploading files");
}
```

I am checking whether the process is already running using `GetProcessByName`.
It is not working because after every 1 second the the log file is getting an entry `Started uploading files`

So my log file will be

```
Started uploading files
Started uploading files
Started uploading files
Finished uploading files
Finished uploading files
Finished uploading files
```

What I need is

```
Started uploading files
Finished uploading files
Started uploading files
Finished uploading files
Started uploading files
Finished uploading files
```

ie. with out finishing the first cycle the service should not enter the process. 
Is there a way to achieve this

Comment: u can use lock if (Process.GetProcessesByName("my_process").Length > 0)
 {
//here
}

Answer (score 0):

You could force it as a single instance application using [Sytem.Threading.Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx). Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819773/run-single-instance-of-an-application-using-mutex).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mutex for this. To avoid this problem you use it like this:

```
private static object _sync = new object();
.....

if (Process.GetProcessesByName("my_process").Length > 0)
{
    lock(_sync)//mutex here, so, only one thread will be able to launch this code.
    {
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("my_process").Length > 0)
        {
            writelog("Started uploading files");
            upload_file();
            writelog("Finished uploading files");
        }
    }
}
```

Double check here is for performance. You can remove outter check if you want.