# How to limit running a program one user at a time?

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I have a program on a remote server that I access via remote desktop and I was wondering if there is any way to restrict the program to be used by one user at a given moment?

For instance while user A is using the program, I want to prevent users B,C,etc.. from running it.

Comment: May be "Named Mutex" ?

Comment: Note: the mutex name must start `"Global\"` for this to work between terminal sessions; `"Local\"` (or no prefix) is processes within a single terminal

Comment: @MarcGravell Am not sure about your last point *(no prefix) is in a single process* If no prefix used it will be visible in single session right?

Comment: @MarcGravell IIRC then named mutex will be OS level(in this case terminal login level) where as unnamed mutex is process level.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes, my mistake: " If you do not specify a prefix when you create a named mutex, it takes the prefix "Local\"." - I'll edit my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer

[.NET Check if another application is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848202/net-check-if-another-application-is-running)

Here is an example of one approach (VB.NET):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length > 1) Then Close()
End Sub
```

Though in researching this, it seems that using a Mutex is a better approach, albeit a much more complicated one, because it's possible that, using the simple approach exemplified above, **you could run into trouble if more than one of your processes has the same name**.  This seems to be one of the definitive q&a's on the topic:

[What is a good pattern for using a Global Mutex in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c/229567)

Comment: This should be a comment. [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Nothing went wrong, you could add some code and info to make your answer *prominent*