# start single instance project

Tags: c#, wpf

I want that my application run only single instance, I used for that the code under pasted under, but It gives me an error :

```
Error   1   'MYAPP.App' does not implement interface member 
            'Microsoft.Shell.ISingleInstanceApp.SignalExternalCommandLineArgs
             (System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>)'
            C:\Users\moataz\Desktop\MYAPP 26-06-2013\MYAPP\App.xaml.cs
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84270/WPF-Single-Instance-Application

Comment: Your question is completely different to your title, and your not implementing an interface correctly, right click the interface at top of your class and then click on implement

Comment: Have you checked this SOF post ? It worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646480/is-using-a-mutex-to-prevent-multipule-instances-of-the-same-program-from-running/646500

Comment: @tp1 You should use Mutex for that. See my answer below on implementation.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the article you posted -

> Step 3: Have your application class implement ISingleInstanceApp
>   (defined in SingleInstance.cs).

So, you need to implement this interface for your `App.xaml.cs`.

Though, personally i would suggest you to use `Mutex` to achieve `single instance application`. Detials can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819773/run-single-instance-of-an-application-using-mutex).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check from running processes in system. If your application name is in running processes , don't run another instance of it your application. Instead bring that instance to view.

Answer (score 0):

Add below piece of code in your App.xaml.cs and see if it works for you.

```
static EventWaitHandle s_event;
bool created;  

App()
{
    s_event = new EventWaitHandle (false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "my program#startup", out created) ;
    if (!created)
    {
        if (MessageBoxResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("Only 1 instance of this application can run at a time", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK))
            App.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: where am I going to add it ? this is my code

Comment: It is mentioned above. Add it in App.xaml.cs

Answer (score 0):

why not use Mutex, You do this in **App.xaml.cs.**

```
 Mutex myMutex ;

 private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
 {
    bool aIsNewInstance = false;
    myMutex = new Mutex(true, "MyWPFApplication", out aIsNewInstance);  
       if (!aIsNewInstance)
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Already an instance is running...");
          App.Current.Shutdown();  
        }
  }
```

Comment: I didn't found Startup in event's visual studio window

Comment: by the way I am using WPF

Comment: where are you looking for it? Quick solution: Search in all files you will find it.

Comment: done, but didn't worked.

Comment: @tp1 the code didn't work? or you didn't find it?

Comment: I have pasted the code bellow to my App.Xaml.cs File,

Comment: that's all i have done !!!

Comment: have you placed the debugger there to see is the code hit? have you changed this "MyWPFApplication" to your application name?

Comment: yes yes i have done that

Comment: @tp1 is the debugger hit?