# Windowed and Windowless Applications Together

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, events

I am working with VB.NET 2013 Express.

I have a solution containing two projects, let's say **AA** and **BB**.

**AA** is a regular WinForms app.

**BB** is a windowless WinForms app.

**AA** may be opened and closed many times throughout the session. When **AA** opens, it should see if **BB** is already running, and if not, launch it.

**BB** will run until the PC (Windows 7) is powered down.

I need some kind of way of testing if **BB** is already running.

I tried writing status to a file, but I do not know how to get a closing event on **BB** to reset status for the next session.

I really do not want to add anything to computer's start-up menu if I can avoid it. Is there a better way?

Comment: [Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you need, but two ways come to mind.

**Check to see if the BB process is running**

This is the easiest and quickest way, in my opinion. Just check to see if the BB process is running before hand, then do whatever:

```
bool IsProcessRunning(string processName)
{
        return (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).Length != 0);
}
```

**Make BB a single instance form and just call it every time from AA**

See this post about making single instance WinForms

[What is the correct way to create a single instance application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application)

This way you can just call BB every time without needing to first check if it's running.

Comment: For some reason, this is not working. I always get an empty array of processes. The task manager appends `" *32"` to the executable name, I have tried doing the same, but that did not help, I still got a zero length array.

Comment: Have you tried running the app as admin? Sounds like you don't have permission to check running processes. Maybe you can add some code to your answer if it's still not working because my way is definitely right ;-)

Comment: I got it working using Mutex. Thanks for the tip. It seems to be a cleaner solution too, though I may be wrong. I basically followed this example here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2627466/2228746

Answer (score 1):

```
bool bbexists = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("BB").Length > 0 ;
```

If needed, you can get/check BB process name:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName
```