# What is the best way to make a single instance application in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the correct way to create a single instance application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application)
>   [Prevent multiple instances of a given app in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93989/prevent-multiple-instances-of-a-given-app-in-net)

Do I check whether another process with the same name exists? (What if the user doesn't have permission to do that?)

Write a file to disk and delete it before exiting? (what about abnormal termination?)

What would be a best practice to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application

Comment: Multiple duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93989/prevent-multiple-instances-of-a-given-app-in-net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906100/run-one-instance-from-the-application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a Mutex.

```
bool firstInstance = true;
using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "MyApplicationName", out firstInstance))
{
    if (firstInstance)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
    else
    {
        // Another instance loaded
    }
}
```

Comment: The using statement here is important. Always combine the Mutex with: a using statement or GC.KeepAlive(..) or make the Mutex static. You want to prevent the garbage collector from cleaning up your Mutex. Still WindowsFormsApplicationsBase would be my preferred approach.

Comment: What would it be for the compact framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Process` class's `GetProcessesByName` method to look for another running process with the same name, and exit if you find one.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a named mutex works best.  Here's a link to en example: http://www.iridescence.no/post/CreatingaSingleInstanceApplicationinC.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I depends on the technique you're using. There are quite a few solutions, some more suitable for WPF, some for WinForms:

- WindowsFormsApplicationsBase (my preferred way)
- With a Mutex (bit more complex)
- Checking for a process with the same details (I dislike this one)

More on WindowsFormsApplicationsBase:
http://www.openwinforms.com/single_instance_application.html

More on Mutex and checking a process:
http://www.ravinderweb.com/page/Single-Instance-of-the-Application-using-C-Trick-and-Mutex.aspx

I wouldn't use a File, it's prone to errors and not having File access might even cause Exceptions in your program even though it's not a crucial part of your application.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, all of which have their advantages and disadvantages, and googling will give you a lot of discussion about it.

The methods you describe have the weaknesses you mention.  Also you need to consider how unique you want your instance to be:

- per WindowStation
- per machine

I have a class that can be used to force a single instance per WindowStation for Windows Forms applications.  Basically it uses P/Invoke to do the following during startup, protecting against a race condition using a Mutex:

- Define a fixed unique string to identify your app (e.g. a GUID)
- Obtain a Mutex whose name is derived from your unique string.
- Call EnumWindows using P/Invoke to enumerate all main windows.
- In the EnumWindows callback, call GetProp using P/Invoke on each window in turn, passing the window handle and your unique value as arguments.  If GetProp detects a window that has your unique key (i.e. another instance of your application), activate it (PostMessage(...SC_RESTORE...), SetForegroundWindow, SetFocus), then exit your new instance.
- If you enumerate all windows without finding a previous instance, call SetProp using P/Invoke to set your unique value for your application's main form window handle.
- Release the mutex and continue starting up.

In my use case, this solution is better than simply holding a mutex for the lifetime of the process, because it gives a way to activate the previous instance if the user starts a second instance rather than just exiting.  Using GetProp/SetProp gives you a way of identifying your process instance without relying on the process name.