# What is the best way to make a single instance application in Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, startup, single-instance

I've seen all the answers for the standard framework

[What is the correct way to create a single instance application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application)
[Prevent multiple instances of a given app in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93989/prevent-multiple-instances-of-a-given-app-in-net)
[What is the best way to make a single instance application in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145347/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-single-instance-application-in-net/1145371#1145371)

How do I check whether another process with the same name exists using the compact framework?
The 3 parameter constructor is not supported by the CF
Process GetProcessByName is not supported by the CF

Comment: Why don't you want to use mutex? MSDN says it's available for CF. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx (but not for all versions and platforms - is this the case?)

Comment: The 3 parameter constructor is not supported

Comment: @empi Mutex for Compact Framework does not support naming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenNETCF gives you class OpenNETCF.Threading.NamedMutex that let's you create system-wide named mutex.

http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/40db385b-e21b-7c38-6f22-7a7954a30aa2.htm

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the steps described on blog: http://www.nesser.org/blog/archives/56 could help (also check the comments).

LP,
Dejan