# Single Document Interface [how to]

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run one instance from the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906100/run-one-instance-from-the-application)

let's suppose i make an application in C#(winforms), we can run multiple instances of the same application by just running the exe[clr], i want that there should be only one instance allowed... i think its close to the defination of SDI [single document interface]... how to do it.

Comment: SDI does not necessarily mean single instance. Some SDI apps work with multiple processes, and some open multiple windows in the same process.

Comment: thats why i wrote "its close to defination the "

Comment: Yes, I was just pointing out the distinction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a [`Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) to check for just one instance, like explained here: [Using Mutex to force only one instance of Form](http://vvvlad.blogspot.com/2008/05/winforms-using-mutex-to-force-only-one.html) and here [Creating a single-instance application](http://kristofverbiest.blogspot.com/2008/11/creating-single-instance-application.html)

Comment: i like the second option