# Running window service but only if not running already

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-services

I am developing a windows service that takes some invoices from and database and process them.. The service is scheduled to run every 10 minutes.

But the problem is that it starts a new thread after every 10 minutes even though previous process has not completed yet.

**Is it possible to schedule windows service in a way that it runs after every few minutes but only if it is NOT running already (like in windows task scheduler)?**

I have scheduled my windows service as shown in following link:
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Repeat-Task-every-N-interval-using-Windows-Service-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Use process class to see if executable is running.

Comment: Do you want the task to be deferred until the previous task is complete, or just skip an occurrence?

Comment: @NathanWerry: I want to run the process if it is NOT running already.

Comment: Just add a flag that task is running and do not schedule next task until it is running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if another instance of the application is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392031/how-to-check-if-another-instance-of-the-application-is-running)

Comment: Does right-clicking on the project name to bring up a window and then clicking on `Make a single instance application` not work?