# How to creat a class level mutex , which work across process

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a class which logs to a file .this class is used  by multiple threads.
I have use a mutex inside the write function and it works fine with one instance of my application . 
but if I start multiple instance of the application the it crashs.

what is the correct implementation of named mutex at class level that can work across process .

Comment: Which platform?  Which language?

Comment: It would help you showed us a little code and presented the error you are getting.  Ordinarily just using a name in the Mutex constructor ought to be enough.

Answer (score 5):

Use named Mutex. Works for interprocess synchronization.

```
Mutex mut = new Mutex(false, "Global\\uniquename");
```

See this post for best practice for using Mutex:
[What is a good pattern for using a Global Mutex in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

For logging I'd suggest opening (with an exclusive locK) and closing the file for every write. The lock will take care of synchronization. You might try `System.IO.File.AppendAllText()` method - I have a suspicion that it does exactly that.