# Form management in a multi-display application

Tags: c#, winforms, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to figure out the best way to manage multiple forms in a C# application that uses dual-monitors.  The application starts to a "launchpad," which just gives the operator some quick information and a "GO" button.  Pressing that button hides the launchpad and displays a form on each monitor in full-screen.  I've tried to capture the relevant code here:

```
private static List<Thread> _displays = new List<Thread>();

// "GO" button handler
private void OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs args) {
    Launch(new Form1());
    Launch(new Form2());
    WaitForAllDisplays();
}

private static void Launch(Form form) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(LaunchDisplay);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start(form);
    _displays.Add(thread);
}

private static void LaunchDisplay(Object obj) {
    Form display = obj as Form;
    // [snip] logic to place form on correct monitor [/snip]
    display.ShowDialog();
}

public static void WaitForAllDisplays() {
    foreach (Thread thread in _displays) {
        thread.Join();
    }
}
```

It feels a little messy to leave the main thread blocked on this `WaitForAllDisplays()` call, but I haven't been able to think of a better way to do this.  Notice that `Form1` and `Form2` are independent of each other and never communicate directly.

I considered using a counting semaphore to wait for all displays to close, but this is a little opposite of a traditional semaphore.  Instead of executing when a resource becomes available, I want to block until all resources are returned.

Any thoughts on a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At first I thought of this would work:**

You can use Events for example: 2 ManualResetEvent  objects.
The main thread will wait on the events using [WaitHandle.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190839.aspx) and an array of 2 Mutexes.
Each thread gets a reference to 1 event and signals it when it's done (before it dies).

**But then I figured** you're better off using 2 mutexes instead and waiting on them.
This way if a thread is terminated abnormally without "signalling" (=Releasing the mutex) you'll get a AbandonedMutexException which you can and should handle. You can use AbandonedMutexException.MutexIndex  to know which thread caused the exception.

You can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c/1015889#answer-1015889) to see how to handle the mutex and exception

**NOTE:**

1. AbandonedMutexException is new in
   the .NET Framework version 2.0. In
   previous versions, the WaitAll
   method returns true when a mutex is
   abandoned. An abandoned mutex
   indicates a serious coding error.
   The exception contains information
   useful for debugging.
2. This
   exception is not thrown on Windows
   98 or Windows Millennium Edition.

Comment: This is a good approach for handling my mutex problem...  I ended up subscribing to the `FormClosing` events and just keeping a counter of "open dialogs."  I was able to eliminate the need for the `WaitForAllDisplays()` method.  Thanks for the suggestions!