# What is the correct pattern for using a global mutex in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mutex

So I've found this information 
[What is a good pattern for using a Global Mutex in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c/229567)

But it's based on the main entry point of a standard app.
How do you modify this to work for the WPF event model of starting the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the big issue is that when Startup is called by default it calls Show() on the main form.

Since this means the function returns, wrapping the Startup call in the mutex like the original example I linked, the lock on the mutex is released shortly after startup.  If you either change the way Statup opens the main from from Show() to ShowDialog() it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

*When I first answered this, I read and wrote WPF, but thought "WCF". Stupid me. Here's my new answer:*

If it has to be truly global, put your mutex setup in any early event that precedes any use of the shared resource. [`Application.Startup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx) is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking this to create a **single instance WPF application**? If so, I encourage you to take a look at [this project](http://wpfinstanceawareapp.codeplex.com/) I created on CodePlex. It provides an `Application` derived class that incapsulates the logic to create a single-instance/multiple-instance aware WPF application, dealing with inter-instances communication too (i.e. the main application can receive the arguments passed to a subsequent instance).
The source code is available, so you can even check that a global mutex and some WaitHandle are used to ensure synchronization.

To answer directly to your question, the proper place to acquire the global mutex is inside an override of the `Application.Startup` method, since it is called at the beginning (more or less) of the `Application.Run` method, which can be considered equivalent to the program `Main` (of course it is not the same thing, but for the purpose of having a single instance application is enough).

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

In App.xaml: Change Application to InstanceAwareApplication

In App.xaml.cs: Change Application to InstanceAwareApplication
and override OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e, bool isFirstInstance)

Then follow the example here:
http://wpfinstanceawareapp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/53538#530411