# Castle Project - Options for refreshing a Castle Windsor singleton (expire? notify?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, singleton, castle-windsor

I'm using Castle Windsor 2.0 for Dependency Injection in my ASP.NET MVC 2 project.

One of my components holds application configuration data and is currently configured as a singleton (the intent is to avoid frequent trips to the database for values that don't change very often).

```
<component id="Configuration" service="MyInterface, 
    MyAssembly" type="MyClass, MyAssembly2" lifestyle="Singleton" />
```

I just created an administrative site to make changes to the configuration.  The original application holds onto the configuration values until the application pool restarts (not a huge surprise).  The users will want the ability to apply their changes in a timely manner.

**Possible Solutions:**

1. Decrease lifetime of the application pool
2. Have the site admins recycle the app pool if they want an immediate change
3. Switch to another DI container
4. Use a single website for everything
5. Change the singleton to a PerWebRequest
6. Create a mechanism that allows the admin interface to notify the application and refresh the singleton
7. Make the singleton expire after a set time thus forcing a refresh

I think option 7 (singleton expiration) would be ideal, but after reviewing [Castle documentation](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/manual/windsorconfigref.html) it would seem that an expiration feature is not yet available.  The [custom lifestyle](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/usersguide/lifestyles.html) seems like a possible solution but I don't see how I could implement it.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement options 6 or 7?  Maybe there is another solution out there?

Comment: "singleton expiration" is an oxymoron.

Comment: @Mauricio: You are right - I'm probably looking for something between PerWebRequest and Singleton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just call a method on the singleton to reload the settings whenever something changes. Or have a timer internal to the singleton that refreshes it.

Comment: I wasn't notified about your answer (thus the late reply) but what's funny is this is the route I decided to take.  The only kludge was how I got the singleton to check the timer - I bundled the check into the getter for a common property.  Any suggestions on an elegant method to check the timer?

Comment: I always use the Reactive Extensions: `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)).Subscribe(i => Refresh());`

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a dependency on a file - like web.config, but something else - that tells the singleton to reload itself when the file changes?

I am doing something similar with AutoFac for DI but in my case I'm working with in-memory repositories for some smaller collections of frequently-used entites that rarely change. When they DO change via a maintennace website I touch a file which forces a cache entry to be ejected that expires all the cached items, forcing a reload.

Not sure what that equates to in Castle as my solution isn't really related to Autofac either. But maybe rather than a singleton in castle your configuration object could live in asp.net cache and be expired the same way? Castle returns an object that loads the data into the singleton and caches it (with the file dependency) when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Mark 909, but instead of a FileSystemWatcher (which needs a file) I would use a [`System.Threading.Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Mutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

### Web project (with Singleton)

I would extend the Singleton with a Mutex ([see this question to implement a Mutex correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c#229567)). At initialisation of the Singleton I would create a new Thread (using the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Task API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) that blocks on the [`WaitOne()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.waitone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method call. When the Mutex receives a signal, the thread will continue and you can reload the configuration. Don't forget to release the Mutex by calling [`ReleaseMutex()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.releasemutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

### Administrative site

Add the Mutex reference to this application and whenever changes are made that should result in a reload of the configuraten data, release the Mutex with [`ReleaseMutex()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.releasemutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This will cause the Web project (i.e., the Singleton) to be signalled and do the reload. Don't forget to get a hold of the Mutex using [`WaitOne()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.waitone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Since this is a blocking function and it's a website, you may want to consider [`WaitOne(TimeSpan)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190477%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Using a small TimeSpan you could inform users of the Administrative site that the Web project is still busy loading the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something similar using a Singleton in Castle. My singleton uses FileSystemWatcher to watch for change events and then reloads data into dictionary object in the singleton when the file is changed. This file contains fairly static reference data

Of course, you'd need to handle concurrency issues when reloading the data in Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share that Ninject has a rebind method that worked out very well for this scenario.  Switching from Castle to Ninject was relatively pain-free.

```
void MvcApplication_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (/* criteria to refresh singleton */)
    this.Kernel.Rebind<IMySingleton>().To<MySingleton>().InSingletonScope();
}
```