# Two applications having same framework not working simultaneously

Tags: winforms, instance

I have two .NET Winform applications (A and B) inherited from WindowsFormsApplicationBase which are developed on same framework.

In the Main class code if I set  IsSingleInstance = False, it runs A and B simultaneously but it can also run multiple instances of A (or B) simultaneously. I have to avoid running more than one instance of A or B at same time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if you use a named Mutex instead of IsSingleInstance you have complete control over which apps start - see http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/faq/#one.application.instance for an overview and [What is a good pattern for using a Global Mutex in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c/229567) for a detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the provide the executable assembly with a new GUID.

In Visual Studio, you can set the GUID in 'Assembly Imformation...' dialog available in 'Application' tab of the Project proerties.