# Can I access a mutex created by a windows service from a user application?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I'm creating a named mutex in a windows service that needs to be accessible from regular applications. So far I create the mutex with a name similar to Global\< GUID >.

Right now I get an unauthorized access violation when I try to open the mutex from an application. How do I configure the mutex at creation time to allow access to any process in the system?

Comment: Have you looked into using the constructor that lets you set access permissions? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zf2f5bz.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [Mutex.SetAccessControl Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.setaccesscontrol.aspx) to set the desired access rights on it. There is an example at [What is a good pattern for using a Global Mutex in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c)