# Use Mutex(??) to check allow for only 2 living application instances

Tags: c#, mutex, semaphore

I understand that [Mutex can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c) to allow only one instance of my app starting on a single machine. This means that no matter how many desktops are used by an arbitrary number of users, there can be at most one instance of the program running.

Now, instead of only allowing one instance, I want to allow for at most *two*, nothing more. How to do it? I tried code such as this:

```
    public static bool MutexChecking()
    {

            bool createNew1;
            // one set of GUID
            new Mutex(false, "54A8F2C1-6C11-4ED4-8A62-AD7C1D9F7970", out createNew1);



            if (createNew1)
                return true;
            bool createNew2;
             //another set
              new Mutex(false, "5E1C76D0-9897-412B-BD56-64A872F8FDE3", out createNew2);

            return createNew2;

    }
```

The above code works... sort of. It works in all the cases I have tested except this one:

1. Open the program( let's call it `p1`)
2. Open the program again ( let's call it `p2`)
3. Close `p1`.
4. Open the program a third time ( `p3`)
5. Expectation: during `p3` , the above method should return a true ( because `createNew1` should be `true`), but it returns a false ( because   `createNew1` returns `false`).

Why is this so? Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a semaphore, not a mutex. A mutex handles mutual exclusion, a semaphore restricts the use of a shared resource to a maximum number.

Comment: The problem with semaphores is that you have to manually release them. If one of your two instances gets killed without releasing the semaphore, you won't be able to restart it.

Comment: For semaphore, what if different users use remote desktop program ( like Citrix) to login to the same machine at the same time? Will the semaphore handles them as if one user is opening multiple instances of the program?

Comment: Semaphore is not usable if you want to restrict the total number of applications launched-- it is only usable if you want to restrict the number of resources within an application.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in p2 you open the first mutex again. This mutex stays open because p2 keeps it so. When you open the first mutex and find it was already open, you should close it so p2 only keeps the second mutex open and p1 only keeps the first mutex open.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.  You are mistaking the point of the out parameter (createdNew).  From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwe34f1k.aspx):

> When this method returns, contains a Boolean that is true if a local
>   mutex was created (that is, if name is null or an empty string) or if
>   the specified named system mutex was created; false if the specified
>   named system mutex already existed. This parameter is passed
>   uninitialized.

In your case, `p2` has already created the first mutex, so it isn't "created new".

What you want to do is not rely on the application's creation of the mutex, but instead rely on *owning* the mutex.  Try passing `true` as the first argument, and calling [ReleaseMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.releasemutex) when the application exits.

Alternatively, switch to a named semaphore as @ChrisLatta suggests.

Answer (score 0):

What Chris Shain said is correct. What you need to do is to OWN the mutex, not just creating it. Also, you MUST manually **release** the mutex when exiting the application, otherwise other application instances may encounter an *AbandonedMutexException*.

Below is a simple code example of how you might want to implement it. Note that this particular code requires the StartInstance() and StopInstance() to be called by the *same* thread.

```
private static Mutex Mutex1 = new Mutex(false, "54A8F2C1-6C11-4ED4-8A62-AD7C1D9F7970");
private static Mutex Mutex2 = new Mutex(false, "5E1C76D0-9897-412B-BD56-64A872F8FDE3");
private static Mutex AcquiredMutex;

public static bool StartInstance()
{
    if (AcquiredMutex != null)
        return true;

    if (Mutex1.WaitOne(1))
    {
        AcquiredMutex = Mutex1;
    }
    else if (Mutex2.WaitOne(1))
    {
        AcquiredMutex = Mutex2;
    }

    return (AcquiredMutex != null);
}

public static void StopInstance()
{
    if (AcquiredMutex != null)
        AcquiredMutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

---

**EDIT :** Actually, if you want to use *createNew* as a way to detect multiple instances, you probably can do that, but I personally don't recommend it since Mutex is not designed for that.

However, even if you decide to use the *createNew* methodology, you will still need to explicitly **close** the mutex yourself once your application exits.

One advantage that this methodology may have over the previous one is that the Close() method does not have to be called by the same thread that creates it.

Below is a simple code example employing the *createNew* methodology. Note that it is not thread-safe. You will need to use lock() in StartInstance() and StopInstance() to make it thread-safe.

```
private static readonly string[] MutexNames = new string[]
{
    "54A8F2C1-6C11-4ED4-8A62-AD7C1D9F7970",
    "5E1C76D0-9897-412B-BD56-64A872F8FDE3"
};

private static Mutex CreatedMutex;

public static bool StartInstance()
{
    if (CreatedMutex != null)
        return true;

    foreach (string name in MutexNames)
    {
        bool created;
        Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, name, out created);

        if (created)
        {
            CreatedMutex = mutex;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            mutex.Close();
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public static void StopInstance()
{
    if (CreatedMutex != null)
        CreatedMutex.Close();
}
```