# MVVM Light and one instance of an application

Tags: c#, wpf, singleton, mvvm-light

I am developing a WPF application using MVVM Light.

I would like to know how to check and prevent the user from running more than one instance of the application?

Thank you for your help.

Romain

Answer (score 2):

Arik Poznanski write an article about this subject on his blog.

Here is the link to the first [article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/05/28/wpf-single-instance-application.aspx)

And here is the link to the [update](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/04/04/wpf-single-instance-application-update.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can check running processes on application startup and exit if copy is already present:

```
var appProcessName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
var matchingProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(appProcessName);
if (matchingProcesses.Any())
{
    // Exit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is called a single instance mutex.  Google has many results, but I used one recently from this thread for a Windows Forms app.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7810107/1718702

Comment: Yes, I have looked for it on Google before but I did not find any results pertaining to MVVM light. Actually I want to know where to put the code to check for the instance. In App.xaml.cs? In MainViewModel.cs?

Comment: Ah, I don't have any experience with mvvm. Sorry :(

Comment: Did you find out how to do it? The App StartUp event which is the right place to put a mutex for a single instance application on a common WPF scenario is not working.