# same file acess by multiple application

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

```
 **This is Writer Application**     

  public class LogWritter
          {      
           Mutex mutx = new Mutex(false, @"Global\MySharedLog");
           mutx.WaitOne();
            try
            {
             xmlDoc.Load(_logFilePath);
              ///Write Log Code
              xmlDoc.Save(_logFilePath);
            }
            finally
            {
                mutx.ReleaseMutex();
            }
          }
```

This is Reader Application

```
  public class LogReader
         { 
             Load(logFilePath);
              //Reader code    
         }
```

I am writing log in ABC.XML file.That XML file can be shared by multiple processes thats why I use `Mutex` object for locking purpose means if one process is writing log then at the same time another process is come using `Mutex.Waitone()` method Wait incoming process while first process completes writing log and release mutext object in finally.
and i have another Reader application where I want to use ABC.xml file for reading purpose How i use mutext object in Reader application?

Comment: You should have a global mutex provider that will provide the same mutex for every resource. So for several files you probably want a dictionary holding the mutex object for each file.

Comment: can u show me some code.

Comment: Instead of a mutex, why not use the file sharing options of File.Open, specifically, 'None'. This will prevent other processes from opening the file for reading / writing. If the File.Open fails for UnauthorizedAccessException, just wait a bit and try again. Use the XmlDocument.Load (stream) version to load from the File object rather than loading from an URL.

Comment: Skizz I have tried it but fires exception( IO exception) file must be used by another process.thts y i prefer mutex

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy/paste the SingleGlobalInstance class from here: [What is a good pattern for using a Global Mutex in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c)
2. Change you code to:

   ```
     // writer app
     public class LogWritter
     {   
         using (new SingleGlobalInstance(-1))
         {   
             xmlDoc.Load(_logFilePath);
             //Write Log Code
             xmlDoc.Save(_logFilePath);
         }
     }

    // reader app
    public class LogReader
    { 
         using (new SingleGlobalInstance(-1))
         {   
             Load(logFilePath);
         }
         //Reader code    
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You want this to be static so someone can't accidentally make a new instance and get different mutexes.

```
public static class FileMutexes
{
    private static System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Threading.Mutex> mutexesInUse = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Threading.Mutex>();

    public static System.Threading.Mutex GetMutexForFile(string fileName)
    {
        if (!mutexesInUse.ContainsKey(fileName))
            mutexesInUse[fileName] = new System.Threading.Mutex();

        return mutexesInUse[fileName];
    }
}
```