# Acquire and release Mutex over interop

Tags: c#, concurrency, mutex

We have a legacy VB6 executable that can run multiple instances. We'd like certain jobs only allow one concurrent instance.

It seems that an OS Mutex is a perfect fit, as this is a legacy app all new code must be written in C# and accessed over interop.

I have created a class that will acquire:

```
public bool AcquireLock(string JobId)
{
    // get application GUID as defined in AssemblyInfo.cs
    string appGuid = ((GuidAttribute)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), false).GetValue(0)).Value.ToString();
    appGuid = appGuid + JobId;

    // unique id for global mutex - Global prefix means it is global to the machine
    string mutexId = string.Format("Global\\{{{0}}}", appGuid);

    bool mutexExists = false;

    var mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexId, out mutexExists);
    var allowEveryoneRule = new MutexAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), MutexRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
    var securitySettings = new MutexSecurity();
    securitySettings.AddAccessRule(allowEveryoneRule);
    mutex.SetAccessControl(securitySettings);

    return mutexExists;
}
```

And release locks:

```
public bool ReleaseLock(string JobId)
{
    // get application GUID as defined in AssemblyInfo.cs
    string appGuid = ((GuidAttribute)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), false).GetValue(0)).Value.ToString();
    appGuid = appGuid + JobId;

    // unique id for global mutex - Global prefix means it is global to the machine
    string mutexId = string.Format("Global\\{{{0}}}", appGuid);

    var mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting(mutexId);

    mutex.ReleaseMutex();

    return true;
}
```

All seems to work well enough until I try to release the lock:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void ReleaseLockTest()
{
    var target = new MutexConcurrencyHelper();
    var jobId = RandomUtils.RandomString(8, true);
    var expected = true;
    bool actual;
    actual = target.AcquireLock(jobId);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

    target.ReleaseLock(jobId);

    var expected1 = true;
    bool actual1;
    actual1 = target.AcquireLock(jobId);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected1, actual1);
}
```

The second attempt at gaining a lock find the lock already in place. Why does this lock not release?

Comment: One thing i noticed is you never called `Dispose()` on the `Mutex` in `ReleaseLock()`

Comment: A fair point, though I just wrapped it in a using statment: `using (var mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting(mutexId))` to no avail.

Comment: Also if I chnage the Mutex instantiation to `new Mutex(false, mutexId, out mutexExists);` I get an `ApplicationException: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.`

Comment: You'll definitely need to re-think this.  The mutex doesn't disappear until you Dispose() the mutex variable or it gets garbage collected.  Your ReleaseLock() makes it worse, it adds *another* reference to the system object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Hans I have created a simpler solution, this also gives us the ability to limit how many instances are running which may also be desirable:

**EDIT:** Added GenerateMutexId for completeness.

```
class SemaphoreConcurrencyHelper: IConcurrencyHelper
{
    private Semaphore _semaphore;

    public bool AcquireLock(string LockId, int Instances)
    {
        try
        {
            _semaphore = Semaphore.OpenExisting(GenerateMutexId(LockId)); //Acquire existing Semaphore (if exists)                   
        }
        catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException) // Create new Semaphore if not exists
        {
            _semaphore = new Semaphore(Instances, Instances, GenerateMutexId(LockId));                
        }

        return _semaphore.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), false); // Block thread until Semaphore has slot available within specified Timespan
    }

    public bool ReleaseLock()
    {
        try
        {
            _semaphore.Release(1); // Increment the count on the Sempahore by 1
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false; //TODO: Add an error log
        }
        _semaphore = null;
        return true;
    }

    private string GenerateMutexId(string LockId)
    {
        // Get application GUID as defined in AssemblyInfo.cs
        string appGuid = ((GuidAttribute)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), false).GetValue(0)).Value.ToString();
        appGuid = appGuid + LockId;

        // Unique id for global mutex - Global prefix means it is available system wide
        return string.Format("Global\\{{{0}}}", appGuid);
    }
}
```

All my test cases pass so far, comments welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The `out` value on the constructor isn't what you want to return to indicate whether the mutex was acquired.  It only indicates whether the specified mutex name was new.  Specify `initiallyOwned` (the first param) as `false` and then `return mutex.WaitOne();`

You'll probably want to make AcquireLock work as a 'try to acquire lock' with a timeout.  Look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229567/571637) for a full example.