# WCF Request/Response logging - Advisable to use Mutex for synchronization

Tags: c#, wcf, logging

Is this advisable to use Mutex object to synchronize request/response xmls writing for WCF service? Is there any better approach for it?

**Background**
We have one very old WCF service which uses by some other Java service and thousands of users use that.

To troubleshoot some prod issues I am implementing logging to capture all the request and response xmls so It will have huge logging.

Since multiple process are trying to write on same xml file i am getting IO exception and to resolve that I thought to use Mutex based on below link however my queries are

- Is this advisable to use it for my service? thousands of requests would hit service in a day so my service would become slower due to mutex ?
- what is the best solution for this type of situation. I am sure this is very common scenario where it is required to log lot to troubleshoot issues in WCF.

OR
**LOCK OR Monitor Object should be ok in my case while wrinting to log file? my service is with ConcurrencyMode Multiple OR Mutix is required ?**

[System.ServiceModel.FaultException - The process cannot access the file 'xxx' because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724566/system-servicemodel-faultexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-xxx-be)

Note: Since this is very old service, i don't have an option to use Log4Net library here.

Thanks for your help.

Like below method I have around 30 methods which log request and response xml and for that I am getting IO error - file is in use.

**Code**

```
WebMethod1(object Request)
{
  string requestId = Guid.newguid().tostring()
  LogRequestResponse(Request)
  response = CallOtherService();  
  LogRequestResponse(response);
}
LogRequestResponse(object xmlReqRes)
{
    try
    {
         using(StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath, true, Encoding.UTF8))
         { 
            xmlSerializer mySerializer = new xmlSerializer(xmlReqRes.GetType())
            mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, xmlReqres);
         }
    }
    catch {} 
}
```

Comment: how are you logging currently?

Comment: without any kind of synchronization.. Still i am in implementing but realized in some instance getting IO exception so thought to use any synchronization object...

Comment: show us some code.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Added code for your reference. Thanks

Comment: Easiest way would be create a log folder and write logs of each request in a separate file. You are already creating a guid, which can serve as file name. More robust would be to queue your logs and let another service do the log management.