# BackgroundWorker run before previous line of code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, backgroundworker, isolatedstorage

I have a BackgroundWorker that includes read/writes to IsolatedStorage. Right before the worker is run, I read from IsolatedStorage. Do I have to worry about using a Mutex, or will the worker only start once the read is completed?

```
//read from IsolatedStorage here

bgw.RunWorkerAsync();  //includes read/writes to IsolatedStorage
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you have to consider:

- if your code before `bgw.RunWorkerAsync();` is run synchronous,
- if IsolatedStorage operations are performed also as synchronous,
- if `bgw` is going to be only Task/Thread/Proccess using IsolatedStorage (check all events, methods, constructors... - also IsolatedStorageSettings, other methods eg. SaveJpg,
- if you Disposed your ISF and all IsolatedStorageStreams

then there will be no problem and you can do it without Mutex. But IMO it will be much safer/better to use one - [here in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229567/2681948) you have a good pattern.