# is this correct use of mutex to avoid concurrent modification to file?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, mutex

i want to be able to put the code of writing file into mutex so as to avoid any concurrent modification to a file. however, I want only the file with particular name be blocked as critical section not for the other file. will this code work as expected or have I missed anything?

```
private async static void StoreToFileAsync(string filename, object data)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile AppIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (IsolatedStorageFileExist(filename))
        {
            AppIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(filename);
        }
        if (data != null)
        {
            string json = await Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json))
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, filename);
                mutex.WaitOne();
                IsolatedStorageFileStream ISFileStream = AppIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(filename);
                await ISFileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ISFileStream.Close();
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 1:** or should I replace the async write with synchronous one and run as a separate task?

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json))
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                            lock (filename)
                            {
                                IsolatedStorageFileStream ISFileStream = AppIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(filename);
                                ISFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                ISFileStream.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I hope this will work. Mutex is costly as it is kernal object. You can use criticalsection when only one process (With different thread) access the file.

Comment: @Sivaraman can u check (edit1) whether the criticalsection implementation is correct?

Comment: Might have been a better fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, using a `Mutex` with asynchronous code is wrong. Normally, I'd say you should use something like [`AsyncLock` from my AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncLock), and if you want a separate lock per file, then you'll need a dictionary or some such.

However, if your method is always called from the UI thread, then it will work. It is not very efficient, but it will work.

Comment: Isnt there exists some kind of async mutex? I assume, having mutex with file name (+ some uid) would solve the problem without dictionary, isnt it?

Comment: There is not an asynchronous *named* mutex, no.

Answer (score 2):

There are few things you should improve:

- running asynchronous code 'inside' Mutex is not good, as the same thread should create and release Mutex. You will probably get exception when called not from UI thread.
- `filename` is not a good name for a Mutex - it is global object (among all processes), so it should be unique.
- you should Dispose your Mutex, and Relese it in finally clause (what happens if you get an Exception?)- [BTW here is a good pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229567/2681948)
- you should/must Dispose IsolatedFileStream
- you should also think if infinite waiting is a good choice
- if you aren't accessing to file amopng processes (Bacground Agents, other App) then you can use [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) or [SemaphoreSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx)

---

```
private async static void StoreToFileAsync(string filename, object data)
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile AppIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (IsolatedStorageFileExist(filename))
            AppIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(filename);
        if (data != null)
        {
            string json = await Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json)) await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                    using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, filename))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            mutex.WaitOne();
                            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream ISFileStream = AppIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(filename))
                                ISFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        }
                        catch { }
                        finally { mutex.ReleaseMutex(); }
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Removed aynchronous call from Mutex - as it will cause problems when called not from UI thread.

Comment: i cant use lock on awaited operation, so is it okay if replace the **WriteAsync** with a synchronous **Write** and run that as a separate Task?

Comment: plz have a look at the edit 1 in the question. btw why shouldn't I use lock on file name?

Comment: I think it should work. You are just awaiting Writing so with Write run on asynchronous thread it should be the same. As for naming lock - [follow the remarks here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx). I wrote that naming Mutex is not a good choice, for example think that you have same files in different folders. You can also think about waht Stephen Cleary had written with AsyncLock.

Comment: ok, so if I am sure I have just one file with that name in all folders, shouldn't be any problem?

Comment: Better would be to create a `Dictionary<string,object>` with locks. And put your `IsolatedFileStream` into `using` or `Dispose()` it at the end.

Comment: @ay89 I've edited my answer after some more research.