# VM like enviroment on citrix for .net application?

Tags: c#, citrix

We have a new customer that is using Citrix (don't know anything more specific about it yet).
Our application is a normal .net forms application designed with no Citrix in mind.
Our application (and this we cant change) makes sure that only one instance of the application can run at each time by checking/creating a system event.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateEvent", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr CreateEventPC(IntPtr lpEventAttributes, bool bManualReset, bool bInitialState, string lpName);
```

Is there a way to get our application to run on a Citrix server somehow?
For instance if all users have some kind of Virtual machine like environment where they can run our application?
An application server? (One of the IT guys mentioned this)
Or some other configuration?
If it helps, the IT guy said they they wipe the citrix enviroment each night...

As you probably understand we have no experience with Citrix and the customers IT department is being uncooperative and not willing to solve this. So we have to prove that it can be done...
We have another customer that have solved this with an external consultant, but they have no idea how...

So any tips or help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you can't change the requirement to have only one instance per user, or you physically can't change the code?

If you're able to change the code, but want to keep the requirement and make it work properly in a Citrix environment, then check out the following thread:

[How to limit instances of a C# program in Citrix to 1-per-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148980/how-to-limit-instances-of-a-c-sharp-program-in-citrix-to-1-per-user/)

If you can't make any change at all to the code, then you could look at an app streaming solution. Streamed apps run in their own sandbox, so when you create global objects like mutexes you won't get any collisions. Citrix does have it's own app streaming solution, so depending on what Citrix license your customer has, they may already have access to streaming without paying additional license fees. The other main Windows streaming solution is Microsoft's App-V, however this requires additional license fees.

Comment: We cant change either the code or the requirement. We are using a framework that has that limitation and we build moduls to that framework for our customer, I will look into the app streaming thing! thanks!