# how to restrict method to be executed one time in multiprocess environement in .net

Tags: c#, .net

I have one exe which will invoke four instances of other exe.So the `Main` method of second exe has following code.But there are situations like two invokes of  `(args[1]=="Test")` will happen.I want to block second invoke ie, want to execute Both methods`(firstmethod(),secondmethod())` one time only.How to do that
these all athe four invokes

```
args[0]   =="leaf"         args[1] =="Test"
args[0]   =="seat"         args[1] =="Test"
args[0]   =="kite"         args[1] =="leveller"
args[0]   =="micky"         args[1] =="sasi"
```

and this is the code in second exe `Main` method

```
if (args[1]=="Test")
{
firstmethod();
secondmethod();
}
```

Comment: I can't say I completely understand your question, but maybe just store a list of which processes (eg `Test`) have already been invoked and incorporating a check into part of your `if()`? (`if(args[1]=="Test" && !alreadyInvoked.Contains("Test"))`)- Again, I may be dead wrong, but don't understand any better what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am talking about the receiving side ie second EXE.What you said is about the invoking side ie first EXE.That will not work here as i want 4 invokes of this second EXE and for this particular block only one time

Comment: From what you've described it sounds like you'll need to use some combination of a Mutex with some means of IPC, perhaps something simple like a lock file, or mapped memory, to communicate that the process has been run.

Answer (score 2):

To restrict activity across multiple processes requires a `Mutex`. The workflow could look something like this:

`second.exe` process is started...

```
if (args[1]=="Test")
{
    bool mutexWasAcquired = AcquireMutex();
    if (mutexWasAcquired)
    {
        if (CheckIfMethodsHaveBeenRun() == false)
        {
           firstmethod();
           secondmethod();
           IndicateMethodsHaveBeenRun();
        }
        ReleaseMutex();
    }         
}
```

To indicate that the methods have been run, the first process to successfully run the methods could create a file which serves as an interprocess indicator.  If `first.exe` is run again, it should check for and delete that file.  That's just one example.

Note that [the syntax required to get safe mutex use correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229567/4267590) is specific and critical.