# File level locking Properties.Settings

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, properties.settings

I am pretty new to C# and wanted to save some settings. My application has to be able to run multiple instances therefore it is a possibility of several simultaneous writes to the `user.config` file. Causing the config file to become corrupted. Therefore I wonder if there are any File level locking when they are saved.

Tried to take a look on the source code for `.Save` and this seems to be boiling down to the interface call `IInternalConfigHost.OpenStreamForWriting`. But it is an interface so I can not easily answer this question on my own.

Updated the wording somewhat.

Basically I am wondering if the user.config file can become corrupt due to several simultaneous writes to it from several instances of my application.

Comment: not sure if I got your question right... several instances reading from one file is no problem at all, but only one can have write access at a time.

Comment: Oh sorry, you pretty much answered my question. Thought several program could have write access at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two or more instances of your program try to write to the same configuration file, you will get exceptions while calling `.Save`

What you can do is use the [Mutex Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to synchronize access from multiple instances. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c) on how to do it properly.

However, one thing that you need to think about is : if one of your instances updates the configuration file, should the others be notified and reload it to provide a consistent behaviour?

Comment: This is the answer since it solves file write problem. As for notifying updates. Yes I need that to. However that's a different talk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mutex lock object.
It is prevents simulataneouse access to shared object bewtween multi thread and multi process.

Reference following page.
http://derpturkey.com/c-cross-process-synchronization/