# Locking a method across applications using a mutex

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 3 seperate project . Named as

1. SharedData -> Class Library
2. Thread 1 -> Window application
3. Thread 2 -> Console Application

SharedData contains the following 2 functions:

```
public class SharedData
{
    static private Mutex mut = new Mutex();

    public static void PrintNumbersMutex()
    {

        mut.WaitOne();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" i = " + i);
        }
        mut.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Thread1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SharedData.DataHolder.PrintNumbersMutex();
    }
}
```

Thread 2:

```
public class User2
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SharedData.DataHolder.PrintNumbersMutex();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

`Thread 1` and `Thread 2` are using `SharedData library`. I have started both project at same time . As I have used `lock` and `mutex` still both project are able to call shared function differently. My problem is if one project is executing shared function other should wait. But it doesn't happening . What is problem could you tell me please.

Comment: You need to show us how you instantiate your mutex

Comment: "I have started both project at same time." That sounds like they're separate *processes* then... so are they using the same global mutex? Just a C# lock won't work, as that's within the process... Fundamentally, we need a [mcve]. (Just a single console app would be fine - it can be launched twice...)

Comment: How to define global mutex?

Comment: As far as I can see this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c which has a very nice answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a global mutex:

```
string mutexId;
if (useGlobal) //Here global refers to across users on that machine
{
    mutexId = String.Format("Global\\{{{0}}}", _appGuid);
}
else
{
    mutexId = String.Format("{{{0}}}", _appGuid);
}
```

The above example uses the applications GUID, from the assembly information for single instancing the app. You can use any unique string though so something like:

```
mutexId = String.Format("{{{0}}}", "MyUniqueString");
```

You define your mutex as:

```
private static Mutex _mutex;
```

And instantiate it as:

```
_mutex = new Mutex(false, mutexId);
```

You can then use the mutex in your method:

```
try
{
    if (_mutex.WaitOne(timeOut, false))
    {
        //Process
        _mutex.RealeaseMutex();
    }
    else
    {
        //Handle not receiving the mutex
    }
}
catch (AbandonedMutexException)
{
    //Handle
}
```