# Multiple independent locks on several objects

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, locking

There are several folders on back-end of Web API server. Each of them is a git repository. Let's call them

- Project1
- Project2
- Project3

How can I create lock on server so only one user (thread) in a project can work with a particular folder? Currently I've implemented simple lock using static object and Monitor class. But in this case access to folders is locked on a global level whereas lock should be applied on each folder independently.

Which .NET threading instrument would be most suitable in my situation?

Answer (score 2):

Locking things globally requires a [Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can give a mutex a globally unique (on the machine) name by using the prefix "Global\" (For example `"Global\\project1"`, `"Global\\project2"` and `"Global\\project3"`) and see if it's in use by somebody else.

There is a solid thread on how to use one perfectly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c).