# Identifying own process name in C#

Tags: c#, process

To prevent user from running multiple instances of my application, I am using this code:-

```
 Process[] pArry = Process.GetProcesses();
           int nCount = 0;
           foreach (Process p in pArry)
           {
               string ProcessName = p.ProcessName;
               ProcessName = ProcessName.ToLower();
               if (ProcessName.CompareTo("myApp") == 0)
               {
                   nCount++;
               }
           }   
           if (nCount > 1)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(AppAlreadyRunning,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
               Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
           }
```

But As we know, Process Name changes if change the exe name.
So If user changes "myApp.exe" to "UserApp.exe", This patch won't work!
Is there any way out?

I am using C# in VS2010.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These questions seems quite similar...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93989/prevent-multiple-instances-of-a-given-app-in-net

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c/229567

Comment: Thanks....Though I searched first, I couldn't find it... This thread is really helpful!

Comment: +1 use of a kernel mode construct such as mutex is definitely the way to do this (although using a semaphore will have slightly less overhead). It's easy to change the process name of a second instance to avoid a check which relies on process names.

Answer (score 7):

This is very simple process. Calling this function returns a process class with all the information you need.

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess()
```

Here is some code for you.

```
       Process[] pArry = Process.GetProcesses();
       foreach (Process p in pArry)
       {
           if (p.Id == Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
                continue;
           string ProcessName = p.ProcessName;
           if(ProcessName == Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName)
           {
                MessageBox.Show(AppAlreadyRunning,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
                Application.Exit();
           }
       }
```

Comment: @Swanand Purankar: although this does answer your question, you should really look at using a kernel mode construct to do this. Even if you are checking process names it's easy for a user to make multiple copies of your exe each with a different name. In that case, your process name check wouldn't stop the user from the running all the exe's simultaneously.

Comment: @AdamRalph Though I am replying almost after a Year & Half, I remember, I used Mutex too... Thanks to Your comment!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I bet you could use Process.GetCurrentProcess() (as you do to kill the process) to get the actual name and use that for comparison.