# how to convert my C# winform program to service program?

Tags: c#, winforms, service

how to convert my C# winform program to service program ?

i need that my program will work like service (like listener)

Comment: What type of Listener you need, TCP, Thread, Http / Web Service ????? Be more specific.

Answer (score 6):

As Darin already pointed out converting a UI application into a Windows service is **in most cases not a good idea.**

This being said, there maybe (or are) edge cases where this can be useful.
I've so far not tried to do it with a WinForms application, but I assume that the steps are almost identical to what I once did.
I wrote a backend application, that runs as a Windows service 99.99% of the time, but can also be started as a console application for easier / faster debugging.

**What you've got to do:**

- prevent the application from spawning multiple instances (optional; [see this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93989/prevent-multiple-instances-of-a-given-app-in-net) on how to achieve this)
- make sure your application does *not* rely on user interaction
- upon startup of the application, check whether it is run as Windows service or in user mode

---

You can detect if the user started the application by querying `Environment.UserInteractive` - which returns `false`, if started as Windows service, and `true` when started in user mode.

your main method should then look something like this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        // do common initialization, logging framework + the likes

        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            // start up in user mode
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new myForm());
        }
        else
        {
            // start up as Windows service
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new myService() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

A windows service doesn't have a GUI, so the sole notion of talking about *converting a WinForms application with a GUI to a Windows service* hardly makes sense. You may take a look at the following article about [writing windows services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) using .NET. If you need to host some sevrice listening on a given port you may take a look at [hosting a WCF service in a managed Windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx).