# How can I enforce a single instance of my application?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, focus

How can I ensure a single instance of my application and to set the focus to it when attempting to open a second instance?

I tried:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern
    IntPtr FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern
    Boolean SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isRunning = Process.GetProcesses()
                                .Where(p => p.MainWindowTitle.Contains(Text))
                                .Count() > 1;

        if (isRunning)
        {
            FocusWindow(Text);
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    public static void FocusWindow(string title)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(FindWindow(null, title));
    }
}
```

This is not focusing the application. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that FindWindow returns a valid HWND?

Comment: Would it not make more sense to check in the Program.cs before launching the form? Check for an instance of the process name with `count > 0`.

Comment: See [Single-Instance Applications in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tyler_whitney/archive/2005/11/28/497604.aspx)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93989/prevent-multiple-instances-of-a-given-app-in-net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to use `Mutex` instead, which avoids to search for windows in a slightly unreliable way (imagine you rename your main form or open another form instead).

```
bool createdNew;
Mutex m = new Mutex(true, "SomeNameHere", out createdNew);

if (!createdNew)
{
    // Application already running. Call it and ask to show it's form.
    IpcClientChannel clientChannel = new IpcClientChannel();
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(clientChannel, true);

    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(typeof(ExchangeBase), "ipc://SomeNameHere/YourAppBase");

    ExchangeBase Exchange = new ExchangeBase();
    Exchange.ShowForm();
}
else
{
    IpcServerChannel serverChannel = new IpcServerChannel("SomeNameHere");
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(serverChannel, true);
    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(ExchangeBase), "YourAppBase", WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    MainForm = new FormMain();
    if (!MainForm.StopLoading)
    {
        Application.Run(MainForm);

        // Keep the mutex reference alive until the termination of the program.
        GC.KeepAlive(m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're passing `Text` as a parameter to your `FocusWindow` method, but while doing a `Contains` check.  I'll bet the Text is only a partial window title and thus, causing `FindWindow` to fail.  Try passing the full text of the window handle instead like:

```
var proc = Process.GetProcesses()
                  .Where(p => p.MainWindowTitle.Contains(Text))
                  .FirstOrDefault();

        if (proc != null)
        {
            FocusWindow(p.MainWindowTitle);
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably caused by the same title of the windows, so the FindWindow get the actual windows handle, try to use the [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28VS.85%29.aspx) function instead of FindWindow.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this check on form load is incorrect. You should use a `Mutex` to make sure only one instance of the application is running. See [this article](http://iridescence.no/post/CreatingaSingleInstanceApplicationinC.aspx) for an example on how to do that and also setting focus to the existing instance.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your App.xaml.cs file:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

#region SetWindowPos Definitions
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
    int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);

const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
const UInt32 SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
const UInt32 SWP_NOREDRAW = 0x0008;
const UInt32 SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;
const UInt32 SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020;
const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
const UInt32 SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080;
const UInt32 SWP_NOCOPYBITS = 0x0100;
const UInt32 SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200;
const UInt32 SWP_NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400;
#endregion
#region OnStartup
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    // Only allow one instance of the application
    Process thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(thisProc.ProcessName);
    if (processes.Length > 1)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();

        SetWindowPos(processes[1].MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
        SetWindowPos(processes[1].MainWindowHandle, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
#endregion
```