# C# How to determine if assembly is running so it cannot be open duplicate?

Tags: c#, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent multiple instances of a given app in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93989/prevent-multiple-instances-of-a-given-app-in-net)
>   [How can I enforce a single instance of my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856441/how-can-i-enforce-a-single-instance-of-my-application)

I have a source then complie to App.exe file. I want if App.exe is running, then a person open it again, it know that it is running and close automaticly. Is there any way to do this?

**Edit: I want a code that insert to source of App.exe

Window Form**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a Mutex, like so:

```
bool bIsSingleInstance;
using (new Mutex(true, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name, out bIsSingleInstance)) {
    if (bIsSingleInstance) {
        // START APP HERE.
    }
}
```

Note that you must *NOT* use 'using' if your winforms isn't blocking in the comment block.