# console application multiple instancing

Tags: c#

I have a console application built in c#. I have scheduled this exe in Windows schedular on frequencies as hour and minute.
When two instances/schedules triggers at same time than it gives an exceptional message.

How can I enable multiple instancing property in my console app?
Really, stuck in it and unable to go out of it?

Comment: What is the error? What is your concole application actually doing at the time?

Comment: This should normally work, unless the application contains logic that doesn't allow more than one instance at a time.

Comment: What's the exception?  As I'm not sure you 'need' to do anything.

Comment: Applications are able to be run multiple times without problems. If your specific application is crashing when run multiple times it means that you have some kind of shared resource both are trying to access. One example would be a file both are trying to open with exclusive access. Without more info we can't say more.

Comment: I am passing a parameter to schduled exe.. for the first instance argument is successfully obtained but for second instance it gives null reference exception:)

Comment: @shanky You really need to put yourself in our situation. You are asking for help with a problem but are not giving us enough information to help you.

Comment: I have a console app which accepts a parameter in static void Main(string[] args). When two instances are triggered on same time than second of them gives Object reference not set to an instance of an object error. Can anyone, please suggest do we have to set any multipleinstancing property in Console app...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question, is you need to do nothing specific to enable multiple instancing.

If there are exceptions occurring it suggests there are shared resource issues e.g. simultaneous IO.

You can however code to 'prevent' multiple instances. See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93989/prevent-multiple-instances-of-a-given-app-in-net) question.  So check if the code contains something similar.