# How do I allow only 1 named Semaphore to be created on a server?

Tags: .net, semaphore

I would like to create a semaphore in my app, where the creation will fail (with a clear exception), if another instance of the app is running and has already created the semaphore. So only one per server.

I'd like the limit of only one to hold across the system, not just the CLR. But I do not want it to hold across multiple servers (or VMs). i.e. I want the app able to run on 2 distinct servers.

Is this possible? If so, how?

thanks - dave

Comment: Are you sure the framework itself is not sneakily creating one or more for its internal usage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent multiple instances of a given app in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93989/prevent-multiple-instances-of-a-given-app-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`System.Threading.Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) for this.

> Named system mutexes are visible throughout the operating system, and can be used to synchronize the activities of processes.

```
bool b = true;
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "MyMutex", out b);
if (!b) throw new InvalidOperationException("Another instance is running");
```

Comment: Is there a way to do a count in a Mutex too? I primarily use the semaphore for the count mechanism. The only one app is a secondary need.