# How do I allow only 1 Java Semaphore to be created on a server?

Tags: java, semaphore

This is similiar to [How do I allow only 1 named Semaphore to be created on a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990181/how-do-i-allow-only-1-named-semaphore-to-be-created-on-a-server) but I am asking here for Java.

I would like to create a semaphore in my Java app, where the creation will fail (with a clear exception), if another instance of the app is running and has already created the semaphore. So only one per server.

I'd like the limit of only one to hold across the server, not just the JVM. But I do not want it to hold across multiple servers (or VMs). i.e. I want the app able to run on 2 distinct servers.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: what kind of semaphore do you mean? If java.util.concurrent.Semaphore, the question has no sense. If some kind of system semaphore, available across all processes, then you should name the operating system used.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Yes a java.util.Semaphore. And I want this to work on any O/S (that's the idea with Java). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could write a `mywebapp.lock` file in the `/tmp` directory, and check if this file exists.

Here's some king of code you could use (not tested) :

Say that `applicationFileLock` is a `FileLock` that would hold the lock during application execution. You can have the following code executed during application startup :

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"),"mywebapp.lock"));
try {
   applicationFileLock = fos.getChannel().tryLock();
   if (fileLock == null) {
     throw new AlreadyStartedApplicationException("Cannot ...");
   }
} catch (IOException e) {
   // handle or rethrow.
}
```

Be sure to release the lock using `applicationFileLock.release()` at the end of the application.

Comment: that file would continue to exist even after the jvm is accidentally killed; preventing any further instantiation of that application.

Comment: Of course, you have to do it using some kind of : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock%28%29

Comment: More sophisticated the file could contain the JVM process id to check if it is alive.

Comment: +1 for nio lock. I believe that to be acceptable for @David's purpose. show some code/example/link for completeness.

Comment: I don't think this will work. What if the app does not have R/W access to that directory?

Comment: `tmp` directory is just an example, file could be placed anywhere where the JVM has write access.

Comment: @GuillaumeDarmont that's not going to work for us. We have customers running this where the system does not have write access to the file system. It wouldn't surprise me if some don't even allow read access (all I/O going to the database).

Comment: No write access at all ? I.E. no GC logs, no filesytem logging, no hsperfdata, ... ? That would be a really bad choice. BTW, if database is allowed, you could still use it as a lock : write (ServerName, PID) in a row. The second starting instance would have to check if this row exists and if PID is exists on ServerName. This time, I'm running out of ideas :)