# c# notify a running process

Tags: c#, process

Is it possible to somehow notify a running process from the "outside"?

I have a C# program that theoretical runs forever. And I would like to notify it to trigger some action manually. It would be best, if this solution is possible on Windows and Linux (mono).

EDIT:

1. The solution should work without a user interface
2. My program is, as for now, a part of web service. On initializing, a new Theread is created, which uses the `Task` class to stay alive

Comment: More context technical information please

Comment: User may click button, another process may own named mutex (windows), network command received... Can you be more specific, don't be shy, tell us what exactly you want to do.

Comment: "A program", console app? windows service? windows forms?...

Comment: If you want to run only one instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93989/prevent-multiple-instances-of-a-given-app-in-net

Comment: There are a huge number of ways a process can listen for notifications. You'll need to narrow things down far more. Eg. what kind of notifications: local or remote; from a user or another program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take your forever-running-process and let it provide a webservice other processes can call.

You might use any cross-plattform webservice framework like [WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api) or [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/) to achieve this via HTTP calls. This will even work over the internet (if the machines can reach each other).

There are dozens of approaches. You could also use [named pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806153/example-of-named-pipes) for example, or put commands into a database (the other process has to query regularly) or - if you're fearless enough - write/read files to communicate. Be creative ...

Comment: So, I just edited my post. I think that it might be confusing when there are urls which sould be accessible to the outside and others thet should only work internally

Comment: Why? Depending on the triggers you want to implement (I assume the new ones will be the ones you called "internally"), you could make one base URL for your internal calls like "/maintenance/triggers/" and call them like "/maintenance/triggers/1/start" or anything like that.

Comment: That sounds actually pretty good. And the named pipes are also helpful, when I may consider splitting the web service and my "program". Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind to accept the answer for all the future users coming to this question? ... and for my ego of course ;)

Comment: Ups, I though this is only possible after some days... Of cause, it's the right answer :)