# How to prevent multiple app loading, but allow loading its different instances?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a test application which could not be loaded a several times. It works fine.

```
 private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
    if (Process.GetProcessesByName(currentProcess.ProcessName).Length > 1)
                    {
                            MessageBox.Show("Instance already running", "Warning");
                            Application.Current.Shutdown();
                        }
    }
}
```

But what if a single user wants to create a shortcut of this application with another instance? For example `"Test.exe" 2`

[image]

This application should be loaded only once, when it was started like "Test.exe 2". I receive this number of instance in `e.Args[0]` and then I need to keep it for compare with another shortcuts of this application at this time.

So here's the question: how do I do it? How can I compare the already existing processes with a different instance's number. Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: @ASh Is there another way instead of using mutex, how do you think?

Comment: Why do you call it an "instance number"? It's just a command line argument. Anyway checking the process name also makes no sense, a user could copy your application and rename the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Mutex` to prevent multiple instances from your app to run simultaneously regardless of the name or path of the executable:

[Prevent multiple instances of a given app in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93989/prevent-multiple-instances-of-a-given-app-in-net)

Comment: Mutex doesn't work

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: I guess not, I can execute many of current applications at the same time

Comment: You shouldn't provided that the name of the Mutex is the same accross all instances. Copy the code and try it out for yourself.